# How do you make an S3 object public via the aws Java SDK?

Tags: java, api, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

How do you make an S3 object public via the AWS Java SDK?

Specifically, what API methods via the Java AWS SDK can be used to make an Object public when its uploaded?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Found the answer in an [amazon aws forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=190170).

```
return s3Client.putObject(
   new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, objectKey, inputStream, metadata)
      .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
```

The answer being

`.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)`

Comment: If you are using transfer managers, this solution also works. Simply replace `s3Client.putObject(` with `TransferManager.upload(`

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that with TransferUtility the Android SDK does not has this feature: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/issues/63

Comment: When using `TransferManager` the following works:
`Upload upload = tm.upload(
        new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, file, metadata)
            .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));`

Answer (score 7):

An alternative approach which allows for more finegrained control of who exactly is allowed to view the object (all users or authenticated users only):

```
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, image);
    AccessControlList acl = new AccessControlList();
    acl.grantPermission(GroupGrantee.AllUsers, Permission.Read); //all users or authenticated
    putObjectRequest.setAccessControlList(acl);
    s3client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
s3client.setObjectAcl("bucketName[/subDirectory]", fileName, CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
URL url = s3client.getUrl("bucketName[/subDirectory]", fileName);
String sharableLink = url.toExternalForm();
```

[source](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=190170)