# Amazon S3 upload file and get URL

Tags: java, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Is it possible to upload a txt/pdf/png file to Amazon [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) in a single action, and get the uploaded file URL as the response?

If so, is AWS Java SDK the right library that I need to add in my java struts2 web application?

Please suggest me a solution for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524041/how-do-you-make-an-s3-object-public-via-the-aws-java-sdk/60052151#60052151

Answer (score -48, accepted):

To make the file public before uploading you can use the `#withCannedAcl` method of `PutObjectRequest`:

```
myAmazonS3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest('some-grails-bucket',  'somePath/someKey.jpg', new    File('/Users/ben/Desktop/photo.jpg')).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead))

String url = myAmazonS3Client.getUrl('some-grails-bucket',  'somePath/someKey.jpg').toString();
```

Comment: How do I get the link out of this request?

Comment: This does not tell us how to get the public url of the uploaded resource.

Answer (score 144):

No you cannot get the URL in single action but two :)

First of all, you may have to make the file public before uploading because it makes no sense to get the URL that no one can access. You can do so by setting ACL as Michael Astreiko suggested.
You can get the resource URL either by calling `getResourceUrl` or `getUrl`.

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = (AmazonS3Client)AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient();
s3Client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("your-bucket", "some-path/some-key.jpg", new File("somePath/someKey.jpg")).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead))
s3Client.getResourceUrl("your-bucket", "some-path/some-key.jpg");
```

**Note1:**
The different between `getResourceUrl` and `getUrl` is that getResourceUrl will return null when exception occurs.

**Note2:**
`getUrl` method is not defined in the AmazonS3 interface. You have to cast the object to AmazonS3Client if you use the standard builder.

Comment: It's worth noting that this only results in a single call to AWS. If you dig into the Java SDK you'll see that `s3Client.getResourceUrl("your-bucket", "some-path/some-key.jpg")` works out the URL without a call to AWS.

Comment: This really should be the recommended answer. The other answer fails for cases where the file-name includes spaces. In such scenarios, the file-name displayed on S3, and the URL suffix, are different from one another. The above s3Client.getUrl method handles this scenario correctly

Comment: Note, `getResourceUrl` is not in the latest sdk.

Comment: It's still there. You may have to cast the interface (AmazonS3) to the  class (AmazonS3Client).

Comment: for latest sdk `s3Client.getUrl("your-bucket", "some-path/some-key.jpg").toString();` will get the public url.

Comment: For even newer SDK versions, try `s3Client.utilities().getUrl(getUrlRequest);`

Comment: `s3.getUrl(bucketName, fileName).toExternalForm()` does the trick in most recent version

Answer (score 92):

You can work it out for yourself given the bucket and the file name you specify in the upload request.

e.g. if your bucket is `mybucket` and your file is named `myfilename`:

```
https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myfilename
```

The `s3` bit will be different depending on which region your bucket is in. For example, I use the south-east asia region so my urls are like:

```
https://mybucket.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/myfilename
```

Comment: After uploading the file from AWS management console, the following links works for a single file, so which one could be the response.. https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.generalsentiment.com/MVR/reports/2010-11_Hollywood_Buzz_Digest.pdf   --  http://cdn.generalsentiment.com.s3.amazonaws.com/MVR/reports/2010-11_Hollywood_Buzz_Digest.pdf   -- http://cdn.generalsentiment.com/MVR/reports/2010-11_Hollywood_Buzz_Digest.pdf

Comment: Yes, there are variations to the url that should work. Pick the one you want to use and go with it.

Comment: Kool..  thanks for the info..  By the way the uploading part am going to do with AWS sdk library right?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. But I have no experience with struts.

Comment: I am almost done with uploading thing.. but strucked at the permissions. Is there a way in the AWS java sdk for S3 to let us make a file public before uploading.

Comment: I suggest you raise a new question, you might get an answer that way.

Comment: Note that using dev.mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myfilename vs s3.amazonaws.com/dev.mybucket/myfilename can make a difference in terms of certificates if the bucket name uses dots. This happens because amazon's s3 certificate doesn't support multi subdomains.

Comment: @Federico what happens if we use bucket name with dots. for ex : "dev.mybucket.com", "static.mybucket.com" etc. can you explain a bit more please ?

Comment: @oko this is related to certificate subdomain policies. Take sub.domain.com and subsub.sub.domain.com. If the certificate supports multiple subdomain *.domain.com will work for both. If it doesn't it would only work for sub.domain.com. Last time I checked amazon didn't support multiple subdomain, so using a bucket name with dots can make a difference if you use it in the domain part of the url.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp With the URL Format mentioned above, I am able to access all the Files inside the Bucket but I am not able to access Individual Files. Can you Please guide me in How to get the UploadPathURL once the upload is completed?

Comment: Sorry mate I have no idea what you mean. If you know the filename, the path and the bucket, you can work out the URL.

Comment: I'm assuming this doesn't work if {myfilename} includes spaces. Example: "picture from vacation.jpg". That's a valid file name which Amazon will accept and display accordingly, though the url will look like "picture+from+vacation.jpg"

Comment: @RvPr of course, it should go without saying that you must encode the filename before rendering any links in a web page. There's more risks than just spaces in a filename if you're accepting end user-specified filenames...

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp, call me stupid, but after reading your answer above, I walked away with the impression that a simple string concatenation would do the job. I hadn't considered that complications may arise, where this approach wouldn't work.  "You can work it out for yourself" doesn't do sufficient justice to the additional parsing that needs to be done. I would recommend editing your answer to mention this complication, and referencing the other answer given below. The getUrl method referenced below doesn't even make a network call, so there's little reason not to use it

Answer (score 20):

For AWS SDK 2+

```
String key = "filePath";
String bucketName = "bucketName";
PutObjectResponse response = s3Client
            .putObject(PutObjectRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName ).key(key).build(), RequestBody.fromFile(file));
 GetUrlRequest request = GetUrlRequest.builder().bucket(bucketName ).key(key).build();
 String url = s3Client.utilities().getUrl(request).toExternalForm();
```

Comment: There is even a more elegant way (in my opinion) by using consumer builder:
`s3client.utilities().getUrl(r -> r.bucket(bucketName).key(objectKey));`

Answer (score 13):

@hussachai and @Jeffrey Kemp answers are pretty good. But they have something in common is the url returned is of virtual-host-style, not in path style. For more info regarding to the s3 url style, can refer to [AWS S3 URL Styles](http://www.wryway.com/blog/aws-s3-url-styles/). In case of some people want to have path style s3 url generated. Here's the step. Basically everything will be the same as @hussachai and @Jeffrey Kemp answers, only with one line setting change as below:

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = (AmazonS3Client) AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion("us-west-2")
                    .withCredentials(DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain.getInstance())
                    .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
                    .build();

// Upload a file as a new object with ContentType and title specified.
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, stringObjKeyName, fileToUpload);
s3Client.putObject(request);
URL s3Url = s3Client.getUrl(bucketName, stringObjKeyName);
logger.info("S3 url is " + s3Url.toExternalForm());
```

This will generate url like:
    https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/mybucket/myfilename

Answer (score 8):

Similarly if you want link through s3Client you can use below.

```
System.out.println("filelink: " + s3Client.getUrl("your_bucket_name", "your_file_key"));
```

Comment: i tried every single solution and this is the only one that worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 2):

a bit old but still for anyone stumbling upon this in the future:

you can do it with one line assuming you already wrote the CredentialProvider and the AmazonS3Client.

it will look like this:

```
 String ImageURL = String.valueOf(s3.getUrl(
                                  ConstantsAWS3.BUCKET_NAME, //The S3 Bucket To Upload To
                                  file.getName())); //The key for the uploaded object
```

and if you didn't wrote the CredentialProvider and the AmazonS3Client then just add them before getting the URL like this:

```
  CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
        getApplicationContext(),
        "POOL_ID", // Identity pool ID
        Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Below method uploads file in a particular folder in a bucket and return the generated url of the file uploaded.

```java
private String uploadFileToS3Bucket(final String bucketName, final File file) {
    final String uniqueFileName = uploadFolder + "/" + file.getName();
    LOGGER.info("Uploading file with name= " + uniqueFileName);
    final PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, uniqueFileName, file);
    amazonS3.putObject(putObjectRequest);
    return ((AmazonS3Client) amazonS3).getResourceUrl(bucketName, uniqueFileName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using AWS-SDK, the `data` object returned contains the Object URL in `data.Location`

```html
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const s3 = new AWS.S3(config)

s3.upload(params).promise()
    .then((data)=>{
        console.log(data.Location)
    })
    .catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Link : " + s3Object.getObjectContent().getHttpRequest().getURI());
```

With this code you can retrieve the link of already uploaded file to S3 bucket.