# Using aws-api s3.upload gives 403 error on file location

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

How I can access data.Location which is a response from s3.upload from an audio src?

Right now when I try

```
<audio src"{pathToFile}" ></audio>
```

I get this  error in the console

```
GET https://my-buc.s3.amazonaws.com/693v36g6j9o7pdi6qg4gafClean.mp3
403 (Forbidden)
```

Here is my code:

```
    const s3 = new AWS.S3({
      accessKeyId: process.env.REACT_APP_S3_KEY,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.REACT_APP_S3_SECRET
    });

    const params = {
      Bucket: "my-buc", // pass your bucket name
      Key: this.state.filename, 
      Body: this.state.uploadedFile
    };


    s3.upload(
      params,
      function(err, data) {
        console.log(err, data);
        console.log(data.Location);
        this.setState({ pathToFile: data.Location }); //extracting data.Location
      }.bind(this)
    );
```

my-buc policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Id": "Policy##########",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Sid": "St##########",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::699######:user/user"
                    },
                    "Action": "s3:*",
                    "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-buc"
                }]

}
```

Comment: Are the iam user and bucket in the same account ? If so, check you have the permission on IAM user and also in bucket change the resource to arn:aws:s3:::my-buc/*

Comment: Yes, but let me try that real quick

Comment: @JamesDean did not work

Comment: @JamesDean I found another Question and Answer, and the answer said that puclic URL can not be accessed during an s3.upload call, the answer said to do an additional call to get public URL....is that correct ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10975475/amazon-s3-upload-file-and-get-url

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Easy Easy Fix

```
const params = {
  Bucket: "my-buc", // pass your bucket name
  Key: this.state.filename, 
  Body: this.state.uploadedFile
  ACL: "public-read" //public read allows you to use the return URL
};
```