# Amazon S3 file upload not working - Public Read Permission

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-s3

I'm uploading a file to Amazon S3 using the eclipse SDK. Apparently the file uploads, actually you can see a file the same size of the original one (in this case a PDF) but with the same name as the key name. If you click on the file link, you get this:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>2FA4CE8A99D64D5B</RequestId>
    <HostId>
       t3k5TK/5PvqCNFGjtF5ycvpjS4HaTGcSTNrd8I8f4fe0JvFHdLMJnaO8N9MTZJe0fXm5BU6E+zU=
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

For this trial, I allowed all permissions to the bucket, why can't I see the PDF file?

**EDIT**

For downloading/viewing of the uploaded file, the Permission of the File while uploading, needs to be set as Public Read.

Comment: Only allowing the permission to the bucket might not work, you need to set the Public Read property to each file while upload

Comment: Thanks!!!.....I have to set that when uploading? How do I do that?

Comment: yes you need to set it for all the files while uploading, I will provide you the code

Comment: Thank you very much!!!!.... how does this work if I only want to access to upload and also download/view the file only from an specific web application?

Comment: ANy specific web-application access OR request filter based on any IP/Address is not yet provided by AWS i think in S3 yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)` to set the permission as Public Read

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
    try {
        File file = new File(uploadFileName);
        s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(
                                 bucketName, keyName, file).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)); // this will set the permission as PublicRead

     } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStacktrace();
    } 
}
```

Comment: @jhugo. If the solution worked, you can choose it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks!!!!....I'm using that, and getting the error:  Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied...)...so using withCannedAcl is "worse" than before.

Comment: could you please verify that you are having enough permission to uplaod a file in S3. Try using the AWS s3 console once and upload from their GUI. Also check your code once again that you are correctly providing the Permissions.

Comment: I created a policy and attach it to the user that I'm using to connect and I get "Implicitly denied (no matching statements found)" when simulating putObject and putObjectAcl actions on it... the policy is: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/*"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
} ... this is the only permission I have besides the one I use to manually handle S3

Comment: I am not much sure about this policy & its usage, the solution I provided above will solve your problem , mentioned in OP.

Comment: So you say that I skip any policy and grant access to everyone to the file?

Comment: the permission is only read for the file like a picture/pdf can be downloaded by a public user, & if you are not going to provide the file url to any public, it will be private & safe.

Comment: I deleted all policies and now I can open the files I uploaded, but I had to set the permission manually, because I still get the access denied error when using your solution

Comment: See some reference also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524041/how-do-you-make-an-s3-object-public-via-the-aws-java-sdk).