# Amazon s3 implementation for reactjs

Tags: amazon-s3, reactjs

I want to use Amazon S3 image in my reactjs application. When I am using the following code, I am getting forbidden error:

`<img src="http://huddlon.s3.amazonaws.com/profilepictures/profile_pic_1_2016_20_02_21_08_22_928182822.jpg" alt="huddlon" className="avatar"/>`

Comment: Can you provide more information? eg: Do you have an object in your `huddlon` S3 bucket with that name? What are the Permissions on the object?Is there a Bucket Policy on the `huddlon` bucket?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein  i have key,bucketname etc but i dont know how to make use all these information in reactjs , do you know any package to make use of

Comment: The error is related to the permissions on the object (that should be) in S3. Whatever put the jpg file there might need to also set appropriate permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow anonymous users to access this image. You can set it manually on the aws console:

[image: Set a permission to everyone]

Or you can do it programatically. See for example [How to do it in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524041/how-do-you-make-an-s3-object-public-via-the-aws-java-sdk). If your backend is coded with another language, google it and you will easily find examples on the net for that particular language.

**Notice** : Depending on where your React project is hosted, you may also need to enable CORS. [See the aws documentation for a detailed explanation.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a proof-of-concept project on GitHub to go into several details of hosting ReactJS on AWS S3 and CloudFront. [The Wiki](https://github.com/nicc777/aws-react-hosting-poc/wiki) should explain everything.

The project include CloudFormation templates and sample code.