# s3 object not applying correct permissions when created from s3 java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a java/playframework application which puts files to a defined S3 bucket using this code:

```
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(s3Bucket, filePath, file);
    putObjectRequest.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);
    amazonS3.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

(Where s3Bucket and filePath are strings, file is of type File.)

This works fine (object arrives at the right bucket with the right name etc.), and through stating *CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead* I would have expected it to be - obviously - *READABLE publicly* (no view/edit permissions for public).

However, the object in the bucket has the permission *OPEN/DOWNLOAD* for the grantee "*ANY AUTHENTICATED AWS USER*". I would have expected this to be the permission when I set *CannedAccessControlList.AuthenticatedRead*, but not for *PublicRead*?

[In the documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/CannedAccessControlList.html#PublicRead) it is stated that any user omitting AWS key and signature will have access. Maybe I misunderstand this. I can give a single object the permission "OPEN/DOWNLOAD" to "EVERYONE", which works perfectly fine when I enter the object URL to the browser. This is also what I would have thought after reading [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524041/how-do-you-make-an-s3-object-public-via-the-aws-java-sdk).

**So my question is: can I put a S3 object to a bucket through the Java SDK and give it permissions for public read, meaning the file to be accessible via it's url?**

Comment: does your S3 bucket have any bucket policy attached?

Comment: The 'with' methods are designed for chaining, like so:  PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest  = new PutObjectRequest(s3Bucket, filePath, file).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);

Comment: Test the equivalent with the AWSCLI by running: aws s3 put --acl public-read --bucket x --key y --body "xxxxx".

Answer (score 1):

If your entire bucket will be public, you can define a bucket policy to make all new uploaded files public:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::[bucket-name]/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Go to your bucket, click properties and then permissions. There should be an option to add or edit bucket policy.

Comment: I would rather not have ALL files in the bucket public, but just those within a certain "folder" (/beginning with a certain prefix like f.e. /assets/public). So the "Resource"-value would be "arn:aws:s3:::myBucket/assets/public/*" ...? Thanks!

Comment: @konrad_pe did you make sure the policy attached to the user or role that is attempting to put the object has a putObjectAcl permission in that bucket?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on how you make the policies.

Check this out : [S3 IAM policies,bucket policies and ACL](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/security/post/TxPOJBY6FE360K/IAM-policies-and-Bucket-Policies-and-ACLs-Oh-My-Controlling-Access-to-S3-Resourc)

So for default :

> When you create a bucket or an object, Amazon S3 creates a default ACL
>   that grants the resource owner full control over the resource.

and this

> If you want to manage permissions on individual objects within a
>   bucket, S3 ACLs enable you to apply policies on the objects themselves

and DENY always trumps ALLOW

> if no method specifies an ALLOW, then the request will be denied by
>   default. Only if no method specifies a DENY and one or more methods
>   specify an ALLOW will the request will be allowed.

So it is possible that the the bucket policies restricted allow trumps your ACL PublicRead. Try add this allow all and attach to bucket permission see what happens.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "allowall",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllForRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. I guess the "Action" would need to be "s3:PutObject", since the permission is overruled during the put request rather than the get request?

Comment: @konrad_pe : I think you need a few explicit rules in such case.  A rule with "conditions" to explicitly let your app use PutObject, another one for everyone to GetObject.  Since you don't want anyone to upload file to your repo, especially blackhat hackers that make use of your "free" repository. Please run the IAM Simulator to test everything out.

Answer (score 0):

Mea culpa - I found the problem, it was the code I used without PROPERLY analyzing it. Following function was defined prior to calling amazon.putObject from the java SDK:

```
public static String S3putFile(File file, String bucketName, String key, CannedAccessControlList accessControlList) throws IOException {
    if(file == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("file must not be null");
    } else if(bucketName == null || key == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Object parameters (bucketName / key) must not be null");
    } else {
        PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(s3Bucket, key, file);
        //putObjectRequest.withCannedAcl(accessControlList.AuthenticatedRead);
        putObjectRequest.withCannedAcl(accessControlList);
        amazonS3.putObject(putObjectRequest);

        return key;
    }
}
```

You can see the commented line in the ELSE clause - the parametrized CannedAccessControlList object had it's property overwritten with .AuthenticatedRead, no matter which property was given during the function call.

So in the end, everything did just what it should; by commenting the .withCannedAcl(AuthRead) line and replacing it by just filling the putObjectRequest with the accessControlList object, everything works perfectly as it should. The file is readable "by everyone".

Thanks anyway for the leads with the bucket policies etc. - very sorry for sending you on a fool's errand!