# Amazon s3 file Public on upload

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I need to call the withCannedAcl method. It turns images as a public read ENUM, so when the book images are registered in the Bucket, they will have a readable public visibility and all users will be able to view the images.  How can I insert the method into my filesaver file?

Here the withCannedAcl method that i found:

```
.withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
```

this is the filesaver.java where i have to insert that method (could be inside the  s3.putObject():?). I tried but it didnt works.

```
@RequestScoped
public class FileSaver {

private static final String CONTENT_DISPOSITION = "content-disposition";

private static final String FILENAME_KEY = "filename=";

@Inject
private AmazonS3Client s3;    

public String write(String baseFolder, Part multipartFile) {
    AmazonS3Client s3 = client();
    String fileName = extractFilename(multipartFile.getHeader(CONTENT_DISPOSITION));
    try {
        s3.putObject("superkovalev", fileName,
                multipartFile.getInputStream(),                    
                new ObjectMetadata());            
                return "https://s3.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/"                            
                +fileName;
    } catch (AmazonClientException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

 private AmazonS3Client client() {
    AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("xxxxxxxx ",
            xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    AmazonS3Client newClient = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, new 
     ClientConfiguration());
    newClient.setS3ClientOptions(new 
     S3ClientOptions().withPathStyleAccess(true));
    return newClient;
   }

  private String extractFilename(String contentDisposition) {

    if (contentDisposition == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int startIndex = contentDisposition.indexOf(FILENAME_KEY);
    if (startIndex == -1) {
        return null;
    }
    String filename = contentDisposition.substring(startIndex
            + FILENAME_KEY.length());
    if (filename.startsWith("\"")) {
        int endIndex = filename.indexOf("\"", 1);
        if (endIndex != -1) {
            return filename.substring(1, endIndex);
        }
    } else {
        int endIndex = filename.indexOf(";");
        if (endIndex != -1) {
            return filename.substring(0, endIndex);
        }
    }
    return filename;
}

public AmazonS3Client getS3() {
    return s3;
}

public void setS3(AmazonS3Client s3) {
    this.s3 = s3;
}

 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make an S3 object public via the aws Java SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524041/how-do-you-make-an-s3-object-public-via-the-aws-java-sdk)

Comment: Thank you Wim I tried again but i cant fix my filesaver.java could you pls give me a tip how to introduce that method in the filesaver.java ?

Comment: s3.putObject("bucket", fileName,
     multipartFile.getInputStream(),
     new ObjectMetadata()).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead);   
     return "https://s3.amazonaws.com/superkovalev/"       
     +fileName;   **doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer for the question:

```
Policy bucket_policy = new Policy().withStatements(
new Statement(Statement.Effect.Allow)
    .withPrincipals(Principal.AllUsers)
    .withActions(S3Actions.GetObject)
    .withResources(new Resource(
        "arn:aws:s3:::" + bucket_name + "/*")));
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-bucket-policies.html