# AWS Java SDK requiring bucket-owner-full-control?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm pushing files to an S3 bucket and the bucket owner cannot see the files while my role is granted access to write to the bucket. I'm not sure why this is and was hoping I would have to programatically force `bucket-owner-full-control`.

#### Simple Code Blob:

```
      ObjectMetadata metadata = constructMetadata();
      PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, filename, data, metadata);
      s3Supplier.get().putObject(request);
```

It uploads successfully, but not seen by the bucket owner. Any reason as to why this would be?

Comment: Is the account owning the bucket different from the account of IAM user/role you are using to write?

Comment: @franklinsijo yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The S3 objects are owned by the AWS Account that writes them. By default, Only the object owner has all privileges on the object and is not accessible by others, including the bucket owner, unless the access is explicitly granted (via ACL).

This example from [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/amazon-s3-policy-keys.html#grant-putobject-conditionally-1) explains how to grant access to the bucket owner for such objects.

Comment: Fixed by explicitly adding bucket owner full control in object before pushing to s3. thanks

Comment: Viktor's answer gives the exact java code.

Answer (score 16):

```
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, filename, data, metadata).withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.BucketOwnerFullControl);
```

Inspired by [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524041/how-do-you-make-an-s3-object-public-via-the-aws-java-sdk)